# react native component button not enabling

Tags: react-native, redux

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    Button,
    TextInput,
    StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';
const username = null;

const SetupForm = ({onSubmit}) => {

    this.handleUsernameInput = (text) => {
        username = text;
    }
    this.handleSetupSubmit = (event) => {
        onSubmit(event, username);
    }
    this.handleSkipSubmit = (event) => {
        onSubmit(event, false);
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Enter username:</Text>
            <TextInput
                placeholder="Username"
                maxLength={20}
                onSubmitEditing={this.handleSetupSubmit}
                onChangeText={this.handleUsernameInput}
                style={{ marginLeft: 20, marginRight: 20 }}
                />
            <View>
            <Button
                title="Select"
                onPress={this.handleSetupSubmit}
                color="#34A853"
                disabled={username === null}
                />

            <Button
                title="Maybe Later"
                onPress={this.handleSkipSubmit}
                color="red"
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}


export default SetupForm;
```

I have an issue with this Setup Form. it features a username text box I am setting to the value the user enters. `onChangeText={this.handleUsernameInput}`

for the select button I have set `disabled` when `username === null` however this never becomes false when entering text into the text box.

the text box is set to set the username when typing and I can see in the console its working correctly when I press the submit via the keyboard button with the redux action

`{type: "SETUP.REQUEST", username: "aaaaaaa"}`

is there something I am doing wrong here that the button is not becoming enabled when the text is getting set by the `this.handleUsernameInput` method?

example gif:
[http://i.imgur.com/OuMkxHA.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/OuMkxHA.gifv)

I have to click the skip button after typing in a username to make the button enable (go green), I want this to enable whilst typing

Comment: Check to see if your render function is getting called again.  I suspect that it is not since your `username` is not a prop or state variable.  Since the render function isn't called again, the `disable` prop isn't reevaluated for the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like mentioned in the Garrett's comment the component doesn't re-render because there's no prop or state change when you change the text input. You should change the functional component to a ES6 class and save the `username` into the state. There's an simple example of this in the [TextInput's documention](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html)

I'm not sure about your skill level but React's documentation about state and lifecycle is a good read if you are new to React https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html